# My Eclipse environment doesn't browse my project

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, rtc

I'm using RTC and Eclipse Helios. I have a project loaded in my workspace, I can browse it manually just fine, but I can't use the [Ctrl]+[Shift]+T (open type) feature.

I recently deleted a clone project, loaded into another RTC workspace. It might have something to do with that.

So basically, how do I get Eclipse to browse through my project properly?

[EDIT 1]: I am in the java perspective. If i reload my ex-project, I can browse the classes in that one, but not in my new project.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the Java Perspective? What is RTC?

Comment: What happens when you try to use Open Type? Does the dialog appear, or is nothing returned when you search? EDIT: just saw VonC's reply. Ignore my question, if he's already sorted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-clicking on your project and clicking Refresh. I occasionally have this problem (nothing is returned in the Type view) and this resolves it for me. I don't use RTC though, so your issue may be different. I don't know what the underlying cause is.

Comment: although my solution consisted of closing and reopening the project, i'll accept your answer, cuz it's highlighting the same general stupid thing you sometimes have to do with eclipse, to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You must be in the Java perspective to access the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut.

[image: open type]

With RTC ([IBM Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/projects/rational-team-concert/)), your default perspective is "Work Items".

[image]

In that perspective, the shortcut for "Open Type" isn't active.

Solution:

- switch back to the Java perspective.
- display the view (from RTC) "Team Artifacts" and "Pending Changes"

That way, you still benefit from the RTC features while accessing all the usual Java features.

Comment: i am in the java perspective. open type just doesn't browse through my files.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean then go to Window / General / Keys / and check if the bindings aren't masked by another plugin/perspective

Comment: no they aren't. i'm using ctrl +shift+t all the time. it works for some projects, but doesn't for others. thx for the suggestion :|